# Insert a field in a multiple row

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, function

On the POS system's "multiple products add page", it is necessary to add the 'edit_warranty' feature to each row. In addition, the amount of 'edit_warranty' needs to be included in the individual row's 'subtotal'. This will enable accurate calculation of the total cost of multiple products on the POS system.

1. This is My Modal

```
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 id="modal_header" class="modal-title"></h5>
                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="dripicons-cross"></i></span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="row modal-element">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                        <label>{{trans('file.Quantity')}}</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="edit_qty" class="form-control numkey">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                        <label>{{trans('file.Unit Discount')}}</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="edit_discount" class="form-control numkey">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                        <label>{{trans('file.Unit Price')}}</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="edit_unit_price" class="form-control numkey" step="any">
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                        $tax_name_all[] = 'No Tax';
                                        $tax_rate_all[] = 0;
                                        foreach($lims_tax_list as $tax) {
                                            $tax_name_all[] = $tax->name;
                                            $tax_rate_all[] = $tax->rate;
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                        <label>{{trans('file.Tax Rate')}}</label>
                                        <select name="edit_tax_rate" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                            @foreach($tax_name_all as $key => $name)
                                            <option value="{{$key}}">{{$name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="edit_unit" class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                        <label>{{trans('file.Product Unit')}}</label>
                                        <select name="edit_unit" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                        <label>{{trans('file.Warranty')}}</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="edit_warranty" id="edit_warranty" class="form-control numkey">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" name="update_btn" class="btn btn-primary">{{trans('file.update')}}</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

2.1.This is My Function

```
    rowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    edit();
});

//Update product
$('button[name="update_btn"]').on("click", function() {
    if(is_imei[rowindex]) {
        var imeiNumbers = $("#editModal input[name=imei_numbers]").val();
        $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.imei-number').val(imeiNumbers);
    }

    var edit_discount = $('input[name="edit_discount"]').val();
    var edit_qty = $('input[name="edit_qty"]').val();
    var edit_unit_price = $('input[name="edit_unit_price"]').val();


    if (parseFloat(edit_discount) > parseFloat(edit_unit_price)) {
        alert('Invalid Discount Input!');
        return;
    }

    if(edit_qty < 0) {
        $('input[name="edit_qty"]').val(1);
        edit_qty = 1;
        alert("Quantity can't be less than 0");
    }

    var tax_rate_all = <?php echo json_encode($tax_rate_all) ?>;

    tax_rate[rowindex] = localStorageTaxRate[rowindex] = parseFloat(tax_rate_all[$('select[name="edit_tax_rate"]').val()]);
    product_discount[rowindex] = $('input[name="edit_discount"]').val();
    if(product_type[pos] == 'standard'){
        var row_unit_operator = unit_operator[rowindex].slice(0, unit_operator[rowindex].indexOf(","));
        var row_unit_operation_value = unit_operation_value[rowindex].slice(0, unit_operation_value[rowindex].indexOf(","));
        if (row_unit_operator == '*') {
            product_price[rowindex] = $('input[name="edit_unit_price"]').val() / row_unit_operation_value;
        } else {
            product_price[rowindex] = $('input[name="edit_unit_price"]').val() * row_unit_operation_value;
        }
        var position = $('select[name="edit_unit"]').val();
        var temp_operator = temp_unit_operator[position];
        var temp_operation_value = temp_unit_operation_value[position];
        $('table.order-list tbody tr:nth-child(' + (rowindex + 1) + ')').find('.sale-unit').val(temp_unit_name[position]);
        temp_unit_name.splice(position, 1);
        temp_unit_operator.splice(position, 1);
        temp_unit_operation_value.splice(position, 1);

        temp_unit_name.unshift($('select[name="edit_unit"] option:selected').text());
        temp_unit_operator.unshift(temp_operator);
        temp_unit_operation_value.unshift(temp_operation_value);

        unit_name[rowindex] = localStorageTempUnitName[rowindex] = temp_unit_name.toString() + ',';
        unit_operator[rowindex] = localStorageSaleUnitOperator[rowindex] = temp_unit_operator.toString() + ',';
        unit_operation_value[rowindex] = localStorageSaleUnitOperationValue[rowindex] = temp_unit_operation_value.toString() + ',';

        localStorage.setItem("localStorageTaxRate", localStorageTaxRate);
        localStorage.setItem("localStorageTaxName", localStorageTaxName);
        localStorage.setItem("localStorageTempUnitName", localStorageTempUnitName);
        localStorage.setItem("localStorageSaleUnitOperator", localStorageSaleUnitOperator);
        localStorage.setItem("localStorageSaleUnitOperationValue", localStorageSaleUnitOperationValue);
    }
    else {
        product_price[rowindex] = $('input[name="edit_unit_price"]').val();
    }
    checkDiscount(edit_qty, false);
});
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Post RENDERED HTML, not template

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: Mr Gert B comment is to hilarious haha, from the title, i think you need to do some research about dinamic input and in the controller, you just need to loop the input process